# How to filter ng-repeat by value?

Tags: angularjs

I got the following json as source:

```
"available_examinators": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user": {
            "email": "mail",
            "first_name": "First_name",
            "last_name": "Last_name",
        },
        "courses": [
            {
                "id": 1,            
            }
        ]}]
```

together with the following html:

```
  <md-option ng-value="examinator"
    ng-repeat="examinator in uf.data.orderData.available_examinators
      track by examinator.id | 
      filter: { examinator {courses : { id : course.id }}}">>
```

I want to filter so it only shows examinators that have an specific course id but I dont get it to work.

Comment: There is no attempt shown to filter anything. Show what you tried that isn't working

Comment: ah sorry, edit the old code, this is what I tried.  <md-option ng-value="examinator" ng-repeat="examinator in uf.data.orderData.available_examinators track by examinator.id | filter: { examinator {courses : { id : course.id }}}">

Comment: What is `course`? What happened with that filter?  Edit question with a [mcve] and a more detailed problem description as in [ask]. Just stating *"it doesn't work"* is virtually meaningless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, this is the correct syntax:

```
<md-option ng-value="examinator"
   ng-repeat="examinator in uf.data.orderData.available_examinators
      | filter: {courses : { id : course.id }} track by examinator.id">
```

Check a working demo: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/daLyxkez/6/)

> **EDIT**: the `track by` expression must come last - after any filters, and the alias expression

Answer (score 1):

Above was almost correct but it led me to the right answer, beside the above changes I had to move track by to the end of the expression else I tried to filter on only examinator.id

So the correct answer is:

```
<md-option ng-value="examinator" ng-repeat="examinator in uf.data.orderData.available_examinators | filter: { courses: {id: course.id}} track by examinator.id">
```

Comment: You are right, `track by` needs to be last, I edited my answer too